# How to place a layout at fixed position in tabs layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a tabs activity,in which there are 3 tabs.Everything is working fine but I want to add a button at the bottom of the fragment which should be fixed at  position like the FAB .The button layout is visible at the bottom but only when I scroll down the fragment.What I want is the button layout should be fixed at a position even if the recyclerview above it is scrolled.How to achieve it ,can anybody help ?
My xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_messages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padd_5"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/replyLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padd_2"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_border"
    android:padding="@dimen/padd_5">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_reply"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/write_a_comment"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/reply"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The reply layout is showing ,but when I scroll up

[image]

what I want is ,the reply layout should be fixed at a position and the recyclerview content should be behind it .The reply layout should be fixed at the highlighted position

[image]

Comment: you want to add button below recyclerview or over recyclerview?

Comment: @HemantParmar over the recyelerview

Comment: ok than use RelativeLayout instead of linear.

Comment: if I use relative layout then the edittext becomes transparent ,which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_messages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padd_5"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/replyLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padd_2"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_border"
        android:padding="@dimen/padd_5">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_reply"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/write_a_comment"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_reply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="@string/reply"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it shows transparent layout for edittext .What I want is it should be overlapping the recyclerview

Comment: Its same XML posted by you I just changed the parent to `Relative` and added `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your `replyLayout`

Comment: If you want `replyLayout` top of `RecyclerView` just replace `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` with `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` to `replyLayout` and add `android:layout_below="@+id/replyLayout"` to your `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_messages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padd_5"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/replyLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/padd_2"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_border"
    android:padding="@dimen/padd_5">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_reply"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/write_a_comment"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/reply"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Neha U need to display the edit text layout fixed at bottom below the recycler view?
It's working at my end. There is only one change from your code in my answer. The height 0dp.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this i have made some changes.
1. added scrollview
2. changed the layout weight
3. Linear layout to Relative Layout.
4. alignParent Bottom=true

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_messages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padd_5"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/replyLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/padd_2"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="@drawable/custom_border"
android:padding="@dimen/padd_5">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_reply"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:hint="@string/write_a_comment"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_reply"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="3.5"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="@string/reply"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />


</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be very easily done using ConstraintLayout.

Try this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_messages"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padd_5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/replyLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/replyLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padd_5"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_reply"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Comment"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_reply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="Reply"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This constraints reply layout to stay at bottom even when recyclerview is scrolled up / down.
Top area is given to recylcerview which is filled with messages and bottom area to reply layout that you created using LinearLayout.

Comment: Just remember to add    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2' to your app gradle module.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it still shows the reply layout when I scroll the screen ,it should be fixed at a place .Please help if you know

Comment: This strange behavoir is caused by 'CoordinatorLayout app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"'.  It is used to hide action bar and move tabs in its place when user scrolls down.

Comment: One solution as Nilesh mentioned is to add reply layout to activity. Or you can add layout to top that way it stays at top but that won't be a good design.

Comment: @ArslanShoukat yes ,you are right .Thanks for your help